# Watson Speech to Text Python

Tags: watson-conversation

I was trying to work with ***Messenger(Facebook), Watson Conversation, Watson Speech to text*** and ***Python***.
Is there like a way to get the ***User Input Audio via Messenger*** and convert it to text using ***Speech to Text*** so that I can use it on ***Watson Conversation***?

Also aware of the ***Messenger mp4 recording*** that needs to be converted to ***wav format***.

Answer (score 0):

A**mazon Polly is a service that turns text into lifelike speech.** Amazon Polly enables existing applications to speak as a first class feature and creates the opportunity for entirely new categories of speech-enabled products, from mobile apps and cars, to devices and appliances.Amazon Polly includes dozens of lifelike voices and support for multiple languages, so you can select the ideal voice and distribute your speech-enabled applications in many geographies.

Amazon Polly is easy to use – you just send the text you want converted into speech to the Amazon Polly API, and Amazon Polly immediately **returns the audio stream to your application so you can play it directly or store it in a standard audio file format, such as MP3. Amazon Polly supports Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML) tags like prosody so you can adjust the speech rate, pitch, or volume**. Amazon Polly is a secure service that delivers all of these benefits at high scale and at low latency. You can cache and replay Amazon Polly’s generated speech at no additional cost. Amazon Polly lets you convert 5M characters per month for free during the first year, upon sign-up. Amazon Polly’s pay-as-you-go pricing, low cost per request, and lack of restrictions on storage and reuse of voice output make it a cost-effective way to enable speech synthesis everywhere.

> [Here is link](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/)

Comment: Hi I appreciate the help however the what I wanted to do is to get the user recorded audio sent via messenger and convert it to text so that my watson conversation will be able to respond.

Comment: Instead of Watson, you can use lex.